# having trouble find a certain string function

Tags: java, string, comparison

if

```
"blah".equals(string);
```

is equivalent to

```
x == y;
```

what is the string comparison equivalent to

```
X != y;
```

sorry if this is extremely basic. searching proved a bit difficult so far.

Comment: well, that was ridiculously simple. thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

`"blah".equals(string)` is NOT equivalent to `x == y`. The first is a function, the second is a built-in java operator. The default implementation for strings works because stings in java are handled in a special way. But if someone overrides the default implementation of `equals` in a class, you can have `a.equals(b)` but `a != b`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `equals` is not equivalent to `==` in Java, if I remember what I was taught back in college correctly :P. `equals` determines whether two objects have the same "content", while `==` simply compares the two "references".

And I'll try to answer your question, `!"blah".equals(string);` maybe?

Comment: Clarification: 'equals' is a method of the Object class which compares object references. So if your class (or any superclass of it) does not override equals the behavior is the same as that of '=='. Strings are notoriously tricky here because they are a special type of citizen in the land of Java. String literals are stored in the string pool and reused so "abc" == "abc" is true. But if you deliberately circumvent it by doing "abc" == new String("abc") the result is false.

Answer (score 3):

```
"blah".equals(string);
```

evaluates to a boolean, either true if they are equal or false if they are not.
By appending a ! to the front, we take the inverse of that, true if they are not equal, false if they are. This is what you want:

```
!("blah".equals(string));
```

On a more pedantic node, for strings, "blah".equals(string) is not the same as "blah" == string, due to complications you probably don't need to know. Also, I suggest you read up on your Boolean logic.

Also your example of x != y is shorthand for !(x == y)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of writing it is:
    if(!"blah".equals(string))

Answer (score 0):

Does `!x.equals(y)` performs the inequality test you want?